# How can i view the double entry of a field and show only one entry of the other fields?

Tags: php, mysql, join, group-by

i want to show the StudentNo, SubjectCode,SubjectDescription and grade but when ever students get failing grade it generates another entry for all the fields so what i want is to show the studentNo, SubjectCode, and SubjectDescription once while showing the 2 grades in that particular subject of that student..
Example: 
[image]

I want to show only like this:(
07-08-061  EN110  5 / 1)
Here's my Code:

**

```
mysql_select_db($database_strawman, $strawman);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT curriculum.SCode, curriculum.SDesc, grade.Grade, students.StudNo FROM students INNER JOIN (curriculum INNER JOIN grade ON curriculum.SCode = grade.GSCode) ON students.StudNo = grade.GStudNo GROUP BY StudNo";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $strawman) or die(mysql_error());

$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Subject Code</td>
    <td>Subject Description</td>
    <td>Grade</td>
    <td>Student Number</td>
  </tr>
   <?php while($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)){ ?>
  <tr>

    <td><?php  echo $row_Recordset1['SCode']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['SDesc']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Grade']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['StudNo']; ?></td>

  </tr>
  <?php } ?>


</table>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Recordset1);
?>
**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) instead of [SUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) for your aggregate function:

```
SELECT c.SCode, c.SDesc, GROUP_CONCAT(g.Grade), s.StudNo 
    FROM students s
        INNER JOIN grade g 
            ON s.StudNo = g.GStudNo
        INNER JOIN curriculum c
            ON g.GSCode = c.SCode
    GROUP BY c.SCode, c.SDesc, s.StudNo
```

Comment: sorry my bad.. i dont need the sum.. when i use the group_concat it creates an error that says : Notice: Undefined index: Grade in C:\xampp\htdocs\strawman\view.php on line 66

Comment: @PiDO: I rewrote the query to clean up the joins a bit. Does that make any difference?

Comment: i found the error. i put something like this "GROUP_CONCAT(g.Grade) as Grade" and it works! thanks alot! youre  a great help!

Answer (score 0):

you can add a where clause
like

```
where grade > 1
```

(insert the minimum grade to pass)

Comment: it seems it will only show the grades which is greater than one. but also want to print out the failing grade with the passing grade.. so the out put will be 2 grades in one subject..

Answer (score 0):

Group by student number and code, use group_concat to get the 2(+) grades listed out of the grouping.

```
SELECT *, group_concat(grade) as grades FROM students GROUP BY GSTudNo, GSCode
```

Thats the basics, to use your query it'd be something like:

```
SELECT curriculum.SCode, curriculum.SDesc, SUM(grade.Grade) grade_total, students.StudNo, group_concat (grade.Grade) as grades 
FROM students 
INNER JOIN (curriculum INNER JOIN grade ON curriculum.SCode = grade.GSCode) 
ON students.StudNo = grade.GStudNo 
GROUP BY StudNo, GSCode
```

Comment: how can i use this in a join statement?

Comment: @PiDO I edited my answer to use your query.  You will also have to change the php where it says echo $row_Recordset1['Grade']; to say echo $row_Recordset1['grades'];

Comment: Thanks for your answer. yes it seems that i have an error in the echo part and i tried what you said and it worked thanks alot!